# Want to ask a follow-up question regarding magnetrons on aircraft, appropriate?

Tags: discussion

About a month ago I asked the following question, to which I got a very good answer:

[What are magnetrons installed on aircraft used for?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21317/what-are-magnetrons-installed-on-aircraft-used-for)

Now I have a follow-up question, which is "which aircraft models use magnetrons for their radar systems?" However, I'm worried that this answer is too specific for the site, and I'm not sure if anyone will know the answer. In the answer to my question there was one aircraft model listed, but I'd like a more comprehensive list.

Should I ask on the main site, or no?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those "List Of Things" questions: The answer is a list of aircraft types, and would be filled with caveats and conditions. (e.g. Two identical aircraft leave the manufacturing plant, their owners install two different radar systems - one gets a cavity magnetron, the other gets something else -- does that aircraft type "count"?)

While I wouldn't say the question is "off topic" I don't think it's a good fit for the site as a comprehensive and correct answer is not something that can be provided (and the answer could potentially be out of date and less useful in the near future as new radar systems enter the market and older units are either replaced on failure or otherwise superseded).